# How to run multiple Docker Containers in different terminals using Docker compose or with Shell?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have to pull `docker image` from Docker Hub and start running multiple peers as containers.

now, I am manually opening terminal and executing my docker run command on downloaded image but I am planning to automate this process like if I/user want 2 peers to run then I should be able to provide IP Address and Port information to Docker run command and start these peers in different terminals without manual step.

After executing these commands I should be able to store these IP address and port numbers in a JSON file further transactions.

Could you please help me!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Docker compose is a good solution. Have you tried?

Comment: No. I heard that it's a good solution for this problem but not quite sure how to use this. Could you please help me out on this..

Answer (score 0):

Got quick solution for the above problem.. Below is the command I have applied `docker run -d IMAGE NAME /bin/bash` above command runs the container in background process. Also, I am taking network credentials by applying `docker inspect <Container Id>`